# Controller action called twice when action accept parameters. Caused by "shortcut icon" ? Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Basically I was fighting some time double called action in a controller (looked like it was called internally as request was sent from a browser and still was waiting for a respond from a server).

I have identified piece of _SharedLayout.cshtml code that caused it:

```
<link href="favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
```

The MVC controller was invoked with a request for favicon, yet it called whole action with empty parameter...

After I've pointed it to the right path, it stopped calling twice action.

I am using .net core 2.1.

Interesting thing is that in most actions that would accept parameters, there would be no error returned, despite the parameter i.e. = 0 so it couldn't retrieve proper data.

In one case action was called once, repo returned the data, and then action was called again and this time it would return an error to the browser (as parameter was 0 and wouldn't be able to populate the view).

I have checked other actions with parameters and they had same behaviour (called twice, second time with empty parameter, but MVC was returning result for a first call properly populated).

Looks like a bug, or is there something that I am not aware of ??

Comment: You'd best have a look at the routing for you controller. If the favicon request matches the routing for your controller, it will be fired.

Comment: Routing is default and as you can read the behaviour differs. Once it is returning second call result, other time only the first. Routing wasn't changed also since the upgrade from .Net Framework => .net core.